# Angular 4 Routing - All Routes are redirected to Default Route

Tags: angular, angular4-router, teradata-covalent

I've setup a simple routing for my angular 4 app that consists of a sidemenu created using [Tetradata Covalent and Angular Material](https://teradata.github.io/covalent/#/layouts/nav-view) i'm using this [Angular 2/4 Authentication tutorial](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/09/29/angular-2-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial) to handle login, however all child router links are redirecting to the default page(dashboard). Any help or advice would be highly appreciated.

**app.routing.ts**

```
export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'mainpage', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'mainpage' },
  {
    path: 'mainpage',
    component: MainPageComponent,
    canActivate:[AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {path: 'order', component: OrderComponent},
      {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
      {path: 'stock', component: StockComponent},
      {path: 'Report/sales', component: SalesComponent},
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'}
      {path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'}
    ]
  }
];
```

**page.component.html**

```
<td-layout>
  <td-navigation-drawer flex sidenavTitle="EzyAgric" logo="assets:logo" name="Akorion" email="info.akorion.com">
<md-nav-list>
      <a md-list-item [routerLink]="['dashboard']">
        <md-icon>dashboard</md-icon>
        Dashboard</a>
      <md-divider></md-divider>
      <h3 md-subheader>Orders</h3>
      <a md-list-item [routerLink]="['stock']">
        <md-icon>archive</md-icon>
        Stock
      </a>
      <a md-list-item [routerLink]="['order']">
        <md-icon>shopping_cart</md-icon>
        Received Orders
      </a>
  </td-navigation-drawer>
  <td-layout-nav [toolbarTitle]="getTitle()" >
    <div class="example-scrolling-content">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </td-layout-nav>
</td-layout>
```

**AuthGuard.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
      // logged in so return true
      return true;
    }

    // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
    this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
    return false;
  }
}
```

**console output**
[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your app.routing.ts where you define your routes move the wildcard line to the end after you have defined all your routes.

### app.routing.ts

```
export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'mainpage', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'mainpage',
    component: MainPageComponent,
    canActivate:[AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {path: 'order', component: OrderComponent},
      {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
      {path: 'stock', component: StockComponent},
      {path: 'Report/sales', component: SalesComponent},
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'}
      {path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'}
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'mainpage' } // this needs to be after other routes
];
```

Since it is a wild card route angular will hit this route before hitting any other route since routes order matter.

Comment: So now the routes show that they are loading but still redirect after 1 second

Comment: What do your new router events look like?

Comment: Oh sorry turns out i had setup some kind of manual redirection in component ngOnInit thanks that worked heres the upvote

Comment: @DeborahK and i learned this from your course.Thank you so much for your wonderful course..:)

Comment: I am so proud! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You must change Your code similar:

```
export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'mainpage', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: HomeComponent },  
  {
    path: 'mainpage',
    component: MainPageComponent,
    canActivate:[AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {path: 'order', component: OrderComponent},
      {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
      {path: 'stock', component: StockComponent},
      {path: 'Report/sales', component: SalesComponent}
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'mainpage' }
];
```